# Cycles Renderer: ColorRamp ignores previous Set Alpha node

Tags: cycles-render-engine

In Cycles, I would like to separate out an element from an image, and apply a color ramp to it before merging it back. After separating out the element however, the color ramp still operates on the original (unseparated) image. Why is it doing this?

**Done so far**:
I separated out an element of the scene via ID mask, and then applied the mask to the original image with Set Alpha. When I apply a color ramp to the second image, not only does it apply to the cropped out image, but it seems to retain information from the very first input image, as you can see from the Viewers in the image below.

Tried the same setup in Blender Internal but the result is roughly the same.

Is this a bug or am I missing something about how nodes/cycles works?

[image]

Comment: This is normal. Colorramp use only those colors what you adjusted in it. When you adjust the colorramp's colors you can adjust the alpha too. But you don't have to do anything with it, just plug the "Render Layers's" alpha output to the last "Viewer's" alpha input.